# a property of Amijo-type line search algorithm

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am reading

> L. Grippo and M. Sciandrone. "On the convergence of the block nonlinear Gauss–Seidel method under convex constraints." Operations Research Letters (2000).

And have some trouble proving the Proposition 1. Here I reorganize it in my own words

> Suppose $f:R^n\rightarrow R$ is continuously differentiable, and $X\subset R^n$ is a convex closed set, and $\{z_k\}\subset X$ is a convergent sequence such that $lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} z_k=z$. 
> For each $z_k$, let $d_k$ be a descent direction of $f$ at $z_k$, i.e., $\nabla f(z_k)^T d_k<0 $, and satisfing $\forall k,||d_k||\le M$. 
> Consider the line search algorithm: let $\delta\in(0,1),r\in(0,1)$, step size $a_k:=max_{n\ge 1}\{\delta^n:f(z_k+\delta^n d_k)\le f(z_k)+r\delta^n\nabla f(z_k)^T d_k\}$
> Prove: if $lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f(z_k)-f(z_k+\delta^n d_k)=0$, then $lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f(z_k)^T d_k=0$

Note that here $z_{k+1}$ is not obatained via line search along $d_k$, in fact  $\{z_k\}$ is a predefined sequence .
I konw it's obvious from the definetion of $a_k$ that $0\le -ra_kf(z_k)^T d_k\le f(z_k)-f(z_k+a_k d_k)$, thus $lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}=a_kf(z_k)^Td_k=0$. But i find it hard to "separate" $a_k$ and $f(z_k)^Td_k$ or to bound $a_k$ in terms of $f(z_k)^Td_k$ , I've tried but faild. 
Another way i've tried is to prove $a_k->0$, if so from $f(z_k+a_k d_k)\le f(z_k)+ra_k\nabla f(z_k)^T d_k$ i can get $[f(z_k+a_k d_k)-f(z_k)]/a_k\le r\nabla f(z_k)^T d_k$, using mean theorem i have $\nabla f(z_k+\theta a_kd_k )^T d_k\le r\nabla f(z_k)^T d_k$, then the result follows by taking the limits. But i can't prove $a_k->0$

Can anyone share some ideas?

Comment: I've dealt with this article A LOT. While it presents interesting results, it is also very poorly written. I have two suggestions for you: 1) Notice that this is a very abbreviated version of "Grippof, L., & Sciandrone, M. (1999). Globally convergent block-coordinate techniques for unconstrained optimization". This paper is much more detailed and you can find the full proofs in it. 2) The 1999 article is still poorly written (in my opinion). If you have access to Bertsekas - Nonlinear Programming (3rd addition), look in chapter 1 for the parts -->

Comment: <-- on stationary points, gradient methods, line search. The implication on block type methods is immediate.